# How to create a ul-li list from d3 nodes hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nest

I have a d3 nodes hierarchy root-parent-child that I need to output as ul-li so that anything that has d.depth = max(d.depth) becomes a li element, and they are all wrapped by ul elements up to d.depth = 0, e.g.

```
<ul>
  <ul>
     <ul>
       <li>
       <li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
  </ul>
</ul> ...
```

I reckon I must somehow iterate through the data and see if there are children and if not append an li, otherwise append an ul... but how? Thanks!

Comment: how does your data look like.

Comment: @Cyril Lets say data looks like this how can i loop through https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/45/?

Comment: Yes, more less like this - data has a root and then name, children. basically I need to append a ul element for each of the nodes, except for the bottom ones, which have to be li elements. The bottom ones can have different d.depths...

Comment: So I am guessing I need to take d.depth = 0, and create ul element for each of them, then take the d.depth = 1 and check which ones have children, and create ul element for those and li for child-less ones, then take d.depth = 2 and repeat... etc

Comment: @NenadVracar we can iterate through the children via recursion check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
//here chart is the div on which you want to attach the ul and li.
var myDiv = d3.select('#chart')/
.append("ul")//root ul
.append("li")//root li
.text(data.name)//root li name
.append("ul");//to this add ul


//note i am iterating through the data via recursion.
function makeElements(parentDOM, myData){
    myData.children.forEach(function(child){
    //add li element
    parentDOM.append("li").text(child.name);
    //if children then make ul
    if (child.children.length > 0){
        var ul = parentDOM.append("ul");
      //recurse pass ul as parentDOM
      makeElements(ul, child);
    } 
  });
}
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/995huhfq/)